# How can I perform AsyncTask in onDetach() of Fragment (IllegalStateException)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a fragment, and when that fragment is completely removed from the fragment(not just when it is added to backStack), I need to tell the server to unlock an entity on serverside.(It is locked when the fragment is created). So my `onDetach()` method is as follows:

```
@Override 
    public void onDetach(){

        new UnlockEntityAsyncTask().execute();
        Log.v("ResultViewFragment", "View onDetach called");

        super.onDetach();
    }
```

Sadly, By the time the network operation starts, the fragment is no longer attached to activity and I get IllegalStateException:

```
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ResultViewFragment{40f26e18} not attached to Activity
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:603)
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:625)
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at com.amberroad.sigmatickettracker.screen.ResultViewFragment$UnlockEntityAsyncTask.doInBackground(ResultViewFragment.java:395)
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at com.amberroad.sigmatickettracker.screen.ResultViewFragment$UnlockEntityAsyncTask.doInBackground(ResultViewFragment.java:1)
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-11 15:55:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

So I guess the Exception occurs because I am trying to execute code of the fragment when it is not attached to the activity. How do I overcome this?

**EDIT**

The first line of the doInBackground uses a variable of the Fragment (ResultViewFragment) called `mContext` which is initialized to `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` in `onCreateView()`. This causes a problem?

Comment: It's occurs in `doInBackground`. We can only guess without, because AsyncTask does not require existing Fragment.

Comment: It says that `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ResultViewFragment{40f26e18} not attached to Activity` . That line of doInBackground uses a class variable called mContext which is initialized as getActivity().getApplicationContext() in the onCreateView() . I think it cannot access this anymore.

Comment: Well, as it is most of the time, Exception is self explanatory. It's Java, not JS... See vadimvolk's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send your application context as a parameter to your AsyncTask constructor.

```
new UnlockEntityAsyncTask(mContext.getApplicationContext());
```

First line of doInBackground executed at the moment when your mContext is already detached.

Comment: Thanks, it was not only that, I was using things like getString(R.string.xyz); also which gave error,  wrapped all the resources I would need into another object and passed that, then it works :)